# Using jQuery to change prepends

Tags: jquery, prepend

My jQuery so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".spoiler").hide();
    $(".spoiler-title").prepend('+ ');

    $('.spoiler-title').bind('click', function(){
        $(".spoiler-title").prepend('- ');
        $('.spoiler').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 100);

    });

});
```

So obviously its wrong because every time you click its just going to add a '- ' and it doesn't remove the old '+ ' prepend.  So how would you remove that new prepend and return it back to the original '+ '?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you add a seperate `<span>` and control whether it is a + or -, rather than concatenating the string every time?

Comment: Because I'm not very good a jQuery so I never considered it :P

Comment: Well that might be a better (and faster) solution to your problem :)  Easier to manage events, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".spoiler").hide();
    $(".spoiler-title").prepend('<span class="prependedSign plus">+ </span>');

    $('.spoiler-title').bind('click', function(){
        if($(".prependedSign").hasClass("minus"))
        {
            $(".prependedSign").remove();
            $(".spoiler-title").prepend('<span class="prependedSign plus">+ </span>');
        }
        else
        {
            $(".prependedSign").remove();
            $(".spoiler-title").prepend('<span class="prependedSign minus">- </span>');
        }
        $('.spoiler').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 100);

    });

});
```

Comment: It's great!  But it doesn't quite do everything I need it to do.  After you click, the plus disappears and the minus appears but clicking again (to close the spoiler) does not removes the minus and reinstate the plus.

Comment: I've updated it to do what you requested. Basically, it now checks to see if it has the class `minus` and if so, it adds a plus sign. If not, then it will add a minus sign. If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

PYou may keep using prepend but since the content of that span will be eather a + or a -, you can use something like `$('.spoiler-title span').text('+ ');` and than change it with .text('- ').

Please consider this code and make the changes as needed:

```
(function($){ $(function(){
  $('.spoiler-title').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('minus').next('.content').slideToggle();
    if($(this).hasClass('minus')){
      $(this).children().text('- ');
    } else { $(this).children().text('+ '); }
  });
}); })(jQuery);
```

I don't know what you have there, but here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seventh/3wZ9r/2/), so you can see how I did it. Hope it works for you! Also notice that I'm not using $(document).ready(). This change has no effect over the code but it will work the same way and it's "conflict free", so start using it instead. There are other ways to avoid "$" conflicts, but this is the one I personally use.

Comment: It almost worked.  After you click, the plus disappears and the minus appears but clicking again (to close the spoiler) does not remove the minus and reinstate the plus.  Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(".spoiler-title").text('+ ');
        $(".spoiler").hide();

        $('.spoiler-title').bind('click', function(){

             if($(this).text().indexOf("- ") > -1)
             {
                   $(this).text('+ ');
                   $(".spoiler").hide();
             }
             else
             {
                  $(this).text('- ');
                  $(".spoiler").animate({height: 'toggle'}, 100);              
             }

        });

    });
```